# Xamarin.Forms json file stream reader NullException error

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stream'

This is the error. Have been researching some information for a while now but can not find an answer. I copied code and json File from GitHub.

Code:

```
void AddMapStyle()
        {
            var assembly = typeof(PinMap).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"PcgDelivery.MapStyle.json");
            string styleFile;
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                styleFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            map.MapStyle = MapStyle.FromJson(styleFile);
        }
```

Is there something wrong with code or what? Json file is placed correctly. I also tried some different methods for reading json file but as you can see with no results.

Comment: `stream` is null, which means `GetManifestResourceStream` must be failing.

Comment: And what should i do?

Comment: More than likely your file is not in the right place or the name you are using as an argument is not right.,  I can't tell based on the information that you've posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your exception is being throw in GetManifestResourceStream if it is make sure the resource you have is an embedded resource see link for more info.

https://adrianmejia.com/cs-getmanifestresourcestream-gotcha/